# SSL is not working in android

Tags: android, ssl, https, openssl, httpclient

I have a problem in communicating the server through **https** protocol from my android app.

I search alot in google, but still i'm not getting correct solution.

here is my code

**PostActivity.java :**

```
        DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
        HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(GlobalUrl.EXPERT_REGISTRATION_URL); //replacing the test expert url

        File resume = new File(mFilePath);  //Actual file from the device
        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        entity.addPart("fName", new StringBody("first", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        entity.addPart("attachment", new FileBody(resume));

        return client.execute(poster, new ResponseHandler<String>() {
            public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
                Log.e(TAG, "handleResponse: status line  " + response.getStatusLine());
                return EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
            }
        });
```

**MyHttpClient.java :**

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

Context context;

public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", getSSLSocketFactory(), 443));
    return super.createClientConnectionManager();
}
private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        KeyStore localTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
        localTrustStore.load(in, context.getResources().getString(R.string.keystore_pass).toCharArray());
        return new SSLSocketFactory(localTrustStore);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create SSLSocketFactory", e);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

above code is working fine in **http** protocol in same domain.
i check the response in server side and it looks like this

```
Array([Cookie2] => $Version=1
[Cookie] => PHPSESSID=978f91620a34d22234b97fc1ba1ab4a3
[User-Agent] => Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (java 1.4)
[Connection] => close
[Host] => www.domain.com
)
```

body of the request is empty. nothing is received in server side except header field.

My SSL certificate was self-signed.
I found that if SSL certificate is self-signed,then we need to create a Keystore to communicate with server.
I followed [this post](http://kdehairy.com/handling-ssl-certificates-in-android/)  and i created a keystore with root certificate from server.

but still its not working.

> i found that the self signed certificate are not trusted by android.
>   is this true? if it is,then how can i solve this?

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I have had issues with self-signed certificates in the past. Not that this is a solution to your problem, just confirmation.

Comment: @zgc7009 is you solved your issue. if so, please share your solution. it will help me alot.

Comment: It was a while ago, I honestly think we ended up having getting a verified SSL certificate instead of self-signing. I do remember beating my head against a wall for a while with it though.

Comment: thanks for your reply @zgc7009